# Magento - Add configurable product option surcharge to tier pricing

Tags: magento, configurable

When I set up configurable products and they have options that include surcharges (i.e. the 2XL costs +$2.00) and I select the option with the surcharge, the price itself updates, however, the tier pricing associated with that product does not.  So, this is what my customer sees...

Product is $10, the 2XL is +$2.00.  If they buy 10 or more, the product is $6.  When they select the 2XL, the price updates from $10 to $12, but the tier pricing tells them they are still getting it for $6 each if ordering 10 or more.  When they add 10 to their cart, they get the correct price of $8 (the $6 discounted price plus the $2 surcharge) but this is just a bad experience - they think they are getting a deal they were never intended to receive.

How can I add to it so that when the option with the surcharge is selected not only is the price updated, but so is the tier price that displays?

Answer (score 3):

If you now switched to Magento 2, our module might help you: https://commercemarketplace.adobe.com/customgento-module-configurable-tier-prices-m2.html

With it, customers can buy different variations of a configurable product and receive the tier price for the total quantity of all variations they buy.
So you could define tier prices on the simple product level for all children and then set up the module, how it should calculate the total price.
You can even configure if the highest, the lowest or the tier price based on the respective products should be charged.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at an extension called Simple Configurable Products:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html

It will allow you to make the product price dependent on the simple product that is related to the configurable product.  You should be able to set up the tiered pricing on the simple product and have it reflected on the parent.

That extension is not 1.6 compatible out of the box, but the following addresses that issue:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/245061/

Comment: In cases where there are 7 options, say, this creates a lot more work for us.  I'm fine with the functionality just the way it is now.  It's the javascript that creates a problem, since it doesn't update the tier price reflect an update, making it look like a product with a $2.00 surcharge is still actually the same price as long as you buy it in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

Magento allows tier prices for products and prices for individual options. However, tier prices for individual options are not supported. Still there are three ways of realizing tier prices for custom options. The last option is the best, from my point of view:

**1. Displaying the surcharges on basket price rules:**
It is the most elegant option if the products are imported with an import interface from an erp-system. In this case you can generate basket price rules, during or at the end of the import, which deliver discounts on each position. However, there is a major drawback: The discounts on the products are shown as one sum in the checkout. Therefore this option will only be useful in rare cases.

**2. Better Configurable Products:**
For each variant of the product an additional simple product is added. Better Configurable Product makes sure that the tier price is taken from the simple product. However, with many products and many variants, it will quickly become confusing.  All these simple products must be assigned to a configurable product. Furthermore, all products have their own stock. Additionally both of the extensions use numerous rewrites that change the very core of the Magento system.

**3. Generating additional individual options with prices:**
An individual option only allows one surcharge, when 5 are needed - one for each tier price. So you add 5 individual options with different prices.  The advantages of using this solution are moderate changes to the system while displaying the prices for the products in a reasonable way. The solution works with two observers – and additional rewrites of blocks for better visual appearance. Once passed the checkout, Magento just works with standard custom options. Therefore, it is very unlikely to experience problems in the later steps – e.g. invoice, shipment, credit memo and export to an erp-system. The disadvantages are additional options in the backend that are somewhat disturbing when maintaining the products by hand.

There is also a module as a sample for your own development. It requires entering of tier prices and individual options, in the backend. Finally, the prices of the individual options for each tier price are entered in the newly generated options. You can request a copy at  http://www.code4business.de/kontakt-impressum/ free of charge.

For more information about tier prices in Magento with custom options or about the use of the module just have a look at http://www.code4business.de/tier-prices-for-magento-custom-options-en/